# Do...while que retorne numero + 5 un maximo de 8 veces JavaScript

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo preguntando asi que mis disculpas y no lo hago de la manera correcta.

Dada esta funcion debo resolver lo siguiente```

```
function doWhile(numero) {
  //Implementar una función tal que vaya aumentando el valor recibido en 5 hasta un límite de 8 veces
  //Retornar el valor final.
  //Usar el bucle do ... while.

do{
  console.log(numero);
  numero += 5;
  } while(numero < numero+40);
  
}
```

Me retorna el numero y le suma 5 pero lo hace infinitamente. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: `numero < numero+40` Esto es true y siempre será true, ergo, seguirá ejecutándose el bucle.

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente manera. Gracias por ayudar a comprender

```
function doWhile(numero) {
//Implementar una función tal que vaya aumentando el valor recibido en 5 
hasta un límite de 8 veces
//Retornar el valor final.
//Usar el bucle do ... while.
var counter = 0;
do{
numero += 5;
counter++
} while(counter < 8);
return numero;
}
console.log(doWhile(2));
console.log(doWhile(5));
console.log(doWhile(100));
console.log(doWhile(8));
console.log(doWhile(-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que **`numero < numero+40`** se cumplirá siempre y el bucle se repetirá infinitas veces, tu ejercicio te pide que el **`while`** tendrá un límite de 8 veces, tendría que ser así:

```
while (numero < 8);
```

También, te piden que en cada bucle se incremente en **`5`**, este resultado lo puedes almacenar en otra variable. Tu código sería el siguiente:

```js
function doWhile(numero) {
  numero = 0; // será el número que irá incrementando, dependiendo a esto se romperá el while.
  result = 0; // será los resultados que imprimiremos cada vez que el while se repita.
  do {
    result = result + 5; // "result" incrementa en 5 en cada bucle.
    numero++; // "numero" incrementa en 1, así sucesivamente.
    console.log(result);
  } while (numero < 8); // cuando "numero" llegue a < 8, el while se detendrá.
}

doWhile(8);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos los que respondieron. Gracias por la comunidad, prometo ayudar cuando tenga los conocimientos. Es hermoso programar y romperse la cabeza. Lo que tengo que retornar por lo que emtiendo es el ultimo numero por ejemplo si en la funcion tiene un valor de 100 deberia ret9rnar 140 si es 5 deberia retornar 48 y asi pero les agradezco mucho a todos los que colaboran ahora cuando termine el ejercicio lo subo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas una variable adicional para tener el control de las veces que se ejecuta el ciclo, usando el valor recibido en parámetro para incrementar y devolver como resultado:

```js
function doWhile(numero) {
  // Crear una variable para control de ciclo
  let cuenta = 0;
  do {
    // Incrementar el número
    numero += 5;
    // Incrementar el contador
    cuenta ++;
  } while(cuenta < 8);
  // Devolver resultado
  return numero;
}

console.log(doWhile(1));
console.log(doWhile(8));
console.log(doWhile(20));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos los que respondieron. Gracias por la comunidad, prometo ayudar cuando tenga los conocimientos. Es hermoso programar y romperse la cabeza. Lo que tengo que retornar por lo que emtiendo es el ultimo numero por ejemplo si en la funcion tiene un valor de 100 deberia ret9rnar 140 si es 5 deberia retornar 48 y asi pero les agradezco mucho a todos los que colaboran ahora cuando termine el ejercicio lo subo. Muchas gracias